# How to log out from Stack Overflow (SO)

Tags: support, logout

I literally have no idea on how do I log out from Stack Overflow. Can anyone help me with this?

I'm serious, like for real, how the heck do I log off?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in the right corner, up, in the Stack Exchange community list:

[image]

Or you can just click [**HERE!**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/logout).

Answer (score 2):

Click on the Stack Exchange logo at the top right (see picture), and then you can log out.

[image]

Comment: okay... well Stackoverflow isn't known for its very intuitive UI but thank you very much!